# View in use certificates on vCenter Server Appliance

Tags: vmware-vsphere, certificate, vmware-vcenter

I'm trying to find which certificates are in use on a VMware vCenter Server Appliance (VCSA).

For example the current MACHINE or vpxd certificate, where are they located so that I can check the thumbprint and/or export it?

I'm not referring to the VMware Certificate Authority (VMCA) which is about all I can find results for when Googling.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the VMware vCenter Server Appliance over SSH

Open the shell

```
shell
```

To view the certificate store

```
/usr/lib/vmware-vmafd/bin/vecs-cli store list
```

To view details of a certificate in the store

```
/usr/lib/vmware-vmafd/bin/vecs-cli entry list --store <store name from the list generated in the previous command> --text
```